# Using case in select clause?

Tags: sql, db2

I want to use a CASE Statement to check a parameter conditionally like `if parameter is an empty string I want to return Nil if not then string 'test'` but this does not work. Also I don't want to use COALESCE

```
select TEST=CASE '' WHEN '' THEN 'Nil' ELSE 'Test' END,current_timestamp from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

I get an error

> SQL State: 42601
>   Vendor Code: -104
>   Message: [SQL0104] Token = was not valid. Valid tokens: + - AS . Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token =.  Token = is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is + - AS .  This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the token.  The error may be earlier in the statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to be valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :   Do one or more of the following and try the request again: -- Verify the SQL statement in the area of the token =. Correct the statement.  The error could be a missing comma or quotation mark, it could be a misspelled word, or it could be related to the order of clauses. -- If the error token is , correct the SQL statement because it does not end with a valid clause.

Comment: While I accept that [constrained writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_writing) can be a wonderful past time, do you have a reason for avoiding `COALESCE()`?

Comment: @onedaywhen I had a crystal report parameter which was passed inside my query, that parameter could be empty or otherwise. COALESCE works on a database column if I'm not wrong so yeah constrained writing does work sometimes ;), Can you reproduce my query with COALESCE using parameters? Damien.

Comment: Lacking as I do both Crystal and DB2 the answer must be no!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select CASE '' WHEN '' THEN 'Nil' ELSE 'Test' END as TEST,current_timestamp from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Replace *something* by the intended column.

---

For more info, check [THIS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/psmcse.htm).

Comment: @aF.Thanks for the link. I got it working by specifying an alias later.

Comment: you need to remove one select.

Answer (score 0):

Your case syntax is incorrect the correct one is,

```
select TEST=CASE <fieldname> WHEN '' THEN 'Nil' ELSE 'Test' END,current_timestamp from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```